# Cannot Find Where You Change The Order Block On Email Confirmation

Tags: email, email-templates

I'm looking to change "Shipping & Handling" on the email order confirmations. I've looked in the items.phtml and it doesn't mention shipping at all.

Not sure where Magento is pulling this in from?